# Send a string between python programs

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I want to send some simple information, like an int or a string, between two Python programs. I thought of doing it by having the programs read and write from a single-line file. But that doesn't seem to work, since one file seems to block the file. Especially since I want to check for updates every 1/12 of a second or so.

If it did work, my idea use case would be for one program to send a message with

```
with open('input.py','w') as file:
    file.write('hello')
```

and receive it with

```
with open('input.py','r') as file:
    print(file.read())
```

I've been looking into how to do it with sockets, but every 'simple' tutorial seems to be targeted some much more complex use case. So how do I do what I need to do in a way that'll actually work?

Comment: Your question is too broad, sockets probably are the way to go though

Comment: check out pyzmq or tornado or similar libraries that will allow you to implement asynchronous communication over sockets.

Comment: Well, the main reason your example didn't work is because you're trying to write to a file opened in read-only mode and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best route to go is to use the `socket` library. This creates a client-server connection, where you can send strings between programs from there.

**server.py:**

```
import socket                

s = socket.socket()          
print "Socket successfully created"
port = 12345     # Reserve a port on your computer...in our case it is 12345, but it can be anything
s.bind(('', port))         
print "Socket binded to %s" %(port) 
s.listen(5)    # Put the socket into listening mode       
print "Socket is listening"            

while True:
  c, addr = s.accept()   # Establish connection with client
  print 'Got connection from', addr 
  c.send('Thank you for connecting')   # Send a message to the client
  c.close()
```

**client.py**:

```
import socket                

s = socket.socket()
port = 12345     # Define the port on which you want to connect
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port))   # Connect to the server on local computer
print s.recv(1024)   # Receive data from the server 
s.close()
```

**From the terminal/shell:**

```
# start the server:
$ python server.py
Socket successfully created
Socket binded to 12345
Socket is listening
Got connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52617)

# start the client:
$ python client.py
Thank you for connecting
```

As you can see, the client was able to receive the string "Thank you for connecting" by the server, thanks to the `send()` and `recv()` methods from the `socket` library.